# Handlebars partial vs. render vs. template

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, mustache

The [Fire Up Ember.js screencast](https://peepcode.com/products/emberjs) uses `partial`, `template`, `render` to render templates within templates, but I'm still not sure I know which one to use when.

In the same screencast the `partial` is explained as using the context and all data relative to the current controller, while `render` uses the the specified controller's matching template, context etc:

[image: Fire Up Ember.js: partial versus Fire Up Ember.js]

Can someone please clarify the differences between `partial`, `template`, `render` and when (examples) to use which?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The way I understand it, the way they break down is like this:

"render" gives you an entire view/controller/template context of its own to work with.

An example will be a top navigation that includes dynamic pieces. The content will be maintained within a TopNavController and inserted into the application template using "render"

"partial" will insert a template, but that template will be using the current context instead of its own. Partial is also a newer part of the framework, meant to replace using template to some extent.

An example would be showing a list of users and having each user be a relatively complicated piece in the list (avatar, name, email, etc) you can just loop through the list and insert the partial based in the context of each user.

"template" just inserts the template using the current context. I believe it's not good style though to use template to render pieces inside of a template, you should rather use "partial" although template will work the same way for most cases.

Comment: This was very helpful, thanks. Could you also elaborate on the difference between ```{{render}}```/```{{partial}}``` and ```{{view}}``` and ```{{control}}```?

Answer (score 34):

This [chart](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/rendering-with-helpers/#toc_comparison-table) given in ember's website gives a good comparison between render, partial and view.

Here is a snippet image of the comparison given in the website:

[image]

Comment: It might not hurt to pull out snippets relevant to the poster's question.

Comment: I can't tell you how many times I've come thru this answer to get to that chart.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of client side memory usage which one is better, render or partial.
Assuming partial would be better as few lesser objects