# Getting custom controller for Ember view

Tags: ember.js

I have an Ember view with a custom controller. The view needs to know about its parent view, so it declares a "needs". Somehow, however, I can't seem to retrieve the custom controller from the template; the "controller" property is bound to the parent view instead of my current view.

I've created a JSBin that illustratest the problem: http://jsbin.com/muwikora/3/edit

As the output shows, "controller" is bound to ApplicationController rather than MyViewController, which I would have expected.

I'm seeing the MyViewController being created and being available in the route from where I could store it but it doesn't seem like a nice solution. What's the proper way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The handlebars view helper will not allow you to specify a controller to use with your view. It allows you to render a view with the current context which is why you are seeing application controller as your controller, calling `{{view App.MyView }}` inside the application template will pass its context of ApplicationController

The render helper is more what you are looking for it will allow you to create a view/controller stack on the fly.

See revised JSBin: http://jsbin.com/muwikora/4/edit

Checkout this answer for more information: [ember.js + handlebars: render vs outlet vs partial vs view vs control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19982257/ember-js-handlebars-render-vs-outlet-vs-partial-vs-view-vs-control)

I encourage you to also read the discussion about best practices for creating complex views. Using render has some consequences that you should be aware of http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/best-practices-when-creating-a-complex-page-render-vs-component-vs-view/4045/2

Comment: Perfect. It's obviously quite a bit more complicated than I thought, but a view should probably do fine for my use case. Thanks for the pointers!