# Unable to Get External JSON data in template in EmberJS

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, ember.js, ember-cli

I've searched on this topic and have tried multiple things but so far have been unable to solve my problem, so I created an account so I can learn :)

I am learning EmberJS and I am unable to get JSON data from the route in EmberJS to output to the actual template. However a Javascript alert in the route presents the data.

I am calling a third-party API that gets WHOIS information for domains externally over http.

Example JSON output

```
{
  "status": [
    "clientTransferProhibited https:\/\/icann.org\/epp#clientTransferProhibited"
  ],
  "updated_date": [
    "2012-12-04T00:00:00"
  ],
  "contacts": {
    "admin": null,
    "tech": null,
    "registrant": null,
    "billing": null
  },
  "nameservers": [
    "adns1.apple.com",
    "adns2.apple.com",
    "nserver.apple.com",
    "nserver2.apple.com",
    "nserver3.apple.com",
    "nserver4.apple.com",
    "nserver5.apple.com",
    "nserver6.apple.com"
  ],
  "expiration_date": [
    "2021-02-20T00:00:00"
  ],
  "creation_date": [
    "1987-02-19T00:00:00"
  ],
  "raw": [
    "\n   Domain Name: APPLE.COM\n   Registrar: CSC CORPORATE DOMAINS, INC.\n   Sponsoring Registrar IANA ID: 299\n   Whois Server: whois.corporatedomains.com\n   Referral URL: http:\/\/www.cscglobal.com\/global\/web\/csc\/digital-brand-services.html\n   Name Server: ADNS1.APPLE.COM\n   Name Server: ADNS2.APPLE.COM\n   Name Server: NSERVER.APPLE.COM\n   Name Server: NSERVER2.APPLE.COM\n   Name Server: NSERVER3.APPLE.COM\n   Name Server: NSERVER4.APPLE.COM\n   Name Server: NSERVER5.APPLE.COM\n   Name Server: NSERVER6.APPLE.COM\n   Status: clientTransferProhibited https:\/\/icann.org\/epp#clientTransferProhibited\n   Updated Date: 04-dec-2012\n   Creation Date: 19-feb-1987\n   Expiration Date: 20-feb-2021"
  ],
  "whois_server": [
    "whois.corporatedomains.com"
  ],
  "registrar": [
    "CSC Corporate Domains, INC."
  ]
}
```

Here's my code.

`routes/file.js`

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  titleToken: "MyTitle",
  model() {
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://api.who.pm/apple.com",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(jsonData) {
          alert(JSON.stringify(jsonData));
          return jsonData;
        },
        error: function(request, status, error) {
          console.log("Error! " + request.responseText);
        }
      });
      }
});
```

In my `templates/file.hbs` I have tried a variety of things to get the `jsonData` output, however have not been successful. I have tried `{{model}}`, `{{model.data}}`, and a few other things. For now I am just trying to get the data output in the template.

The alert launches successfully when the page is run.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Have you looked here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19982257/ember-js-handlebars-render-vs-outlet-vs-partial-vs-view-vs-control

Comment: @ScottFanetti I have just taken a look there, I apologize for my inexperience but I do not understand how those apply in this case. I am using `{{outlet}}` in my main `application.hbs` that the other routes are displayed through, but not in this specific page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model hook should return a promise or actual data, you return nothing.

The `return jsonData` returns the success function, not the model hook. By the time the success hook is called, the model hook already has returned.

I can just strongly recommend you to inform yourself about javascript functions, callbacks and closures. Also make sure you understand `this` and Promises.

For usage with jQuery you need to know that jQuery 2.x `.ajax()` will return a thenable, but this is not a promise. This is fixed in jQuery 3.x. So for now do use `RSVP.resolve`:

```
model() {
  return Ember.RSVP.resolve($.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://api.who.pm/apple.com",
    dataType: "json",
  }));
}
```